# Create Generic Table Lookup for sql tables in VBA

Tags: sql, vba

I am creating this generic TableLookup in VBA, currently in Access, but I do not want to link to the table and use a normal Dlookup because I am going to use this code in different projects in Excel, Word, and even (with some modifications) some VB.net projects. This code is supposed to find values when there can only be a single value in a table in a SQL Server database.

This is the code I have worked out so far:

```vb
Function TableLookup(ByVal connString As String, ByVal ReturnField As String, _
            ByVal TableName As String, ByVal SearchField As String, _
            ByVal SearchValue As String, ByVal SearchType As String)
    
        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection: Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset:  Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        
        Dim sql As String: sql = "SELECT " & ReturnField & " FROM " & TableName & " WHERE " & SearchField & " = "
        sql = sql & IIf(SearchType = "Number", SearchValue, "'" & SearchValue & "'") & ";"
        
        cn.Open connString    'Your Connectionstring
        
        rs.Open sql
        
        'Assuming there is only one company number per contact
        rs.MoveFirst
        TableLookup = rs.Fields(ReturnField).Value
        
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Unfortunately, on the `rs.Open sql` line, I get the following error:

> Run-time error '3709'
>
> The connection cannot be used to perform the operation.  It is either closed or invalid in this context.

What am I missing? I know the connection string is correct because I imported the table in Access and opened the table before I copied it into the code.

Comment: You open `cn` but then don't use it when opening the recordset.  `rs` doesn't "know" anything about `cn` just because they in the same scope.

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you. I cannot believe I missed that.  Well this code is useful for anyone else who wants to do this I believe.